# HLS media file decryption is not working using VideoJs, FairPlay

Tags: video.js, drm, fairplay

I've tried to play an encrypted HLS media file, but It was not played and occurred errors as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zJ5D.png)

The executable environment was identified in [this link](https://docs.vdms.com/video/Content/Security/Apple-FairPlay-DRM.htm), but it was not played

And tested in [test page](https://sample.pallycon.com/dev/devconsole/player.do?lang=ko#html5-player) of Pallycon, but It was played without a problem.

Execution environments and source code are as below.

## execution environments:

- OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Safari: 13.1.2

## using libraries

- videojs: ^7.8.4
- videojs-contrib-eme: ^3.7.0

## DRM Vendor

- Pallycon

## source code

```
const playerConfig = {
                    src: "https://mz-cm-transcoding-output.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/mz-cm-v1/assets/1604917161khae8nfj/Beach+-+19987.m3u8",
                    type: 'application/x-mpegurl',
                    keySystems: {
                        'com.apple.fps.1_0': {
                            getCertificate: function (emeOptions, callback) {
                                videojs.xhr({
                                    url: "https://license.pallycon.com/ri/fpsKeyManager.do?siteId=<SITE_ID>",
                                    method: 'GET',
                                }, (err, response, responseBody) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        callback(err)
                                        return
                                    }
                                    callback(null, base64DecodeUint8Array(responseBody));
                                })
                            },
                            getContentId: function (emeOptions, initData) {
                                const contentId = arrayToString(initData);
                                return contentId.substring(contentId.indexOf('skd://') + 6);
                            },
                            // return content ID
                            getLicense: function (emeOptions, contentId, keyMessage, callback) {
                                videojs.xhr({
                                    url: <license_url>,
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    responseType: 'text',
                                    body: 'spc=' + base64EncodeUint8Array(keyMessage),
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                        'pallycon-customdata-v2': <token>
                                    }
                                }, (err, response, responseBody) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        callback(err)
                                        return
                                    }
                                    callback(null, base64DecodeUint8Array(responseBody))
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                player.src(playerConfig);
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to retrieve the key using the manifest's key URI (skd://...). Check if it's actually passing by your functions. Is the license acquisition URL correct?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to implement the FairPlay in VideoJs. In my case, it was a CORS issue because the certificate was in a different domain and CORS was not enabled there. So I created an API in my server to return the certificate and it fixed the problem.

If load your get certificate URL (https://license.pallycon.com/ri/fpsKeyManager.do?siteId=<SITE_ID>) in the browser, you can check the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the Response Headers to see what origins are allowed.